# Malformed JSON in Batch when getting Unified Group images

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch API to fetch group images and within batch, single image response contains **"Content-Type":"image/pjpeg**" and that breaks json parsing of the response (unexpected token X in the JSON...).

Request:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id":"88aec8df-ea5e-4ad6-8534-3b1ac70693e2",
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"/groups/88aec8df-ea5e-4ad6-8534-3b1ac70693e2/photo/$value"
    },
    {
      "id":"beeadb9d-02cf-4437-ab7d-7762a58e70a6",
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"/groups/beeadb9d-02cf-4437-ab7d-7762a58e70a6/photo/$value"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Batch response from Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIlaf.png)

Seems that Graph batch does not Base64 encode pjpeg images correctly to response json. Normal **"Content-Type":"image/jpeg"** images in batch works fine.

Did not find anything related to this from known issues.

Comment: Could you share the payload of the request you send and the one you get in response please? Also have you looked at the known issues for batch requests? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#json-batching

Comment: You can verify the issue with Graph Explorer too. 

Find Group with photo "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/pjpeg" (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/photo) and then try batch:
`{
  "requests": [
    {
      "url": "/groups/<groupid>/photo/$value",
      "method": "GET",
      "id": "1"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Microsoft Graph batch because response data is not correctly formatted JSON.  Tried to add progressive jpeg to one group image but that works so it must be something related to how default (generated) images are initialized when group is created. Everything starts to work if user changes group image manually.

Comment: Still facing the issue. Anyone?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Yes we do have a bug with image/pjpeg images not being correctly converted to base 64. Working on a fix for this.

Comment: Superb news. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For sanity purposes: this was a bug in the batch processing that has been addressed since.

Comment: I still see similar bugs in the batch responses occasionally when response status is 503. Here is example of such response body - https://gist.github.com/Bonias/b879cc8fb190fc1f3ecf2ebab2bee70d. As you see JSON response is malformed and can't be parsed. @baywet can you move this issue forward internally?

Comment: Internally raised issues don't get prioritized if they are not critical or linked to customer cases. The best thing people can do to move this forward is to open a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @baywet. Is it possible to open a support ticket without having a paid Azure subscription? According to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support I need a paid Azure subscription. After signing in to Azure portal I can create support request regarding "Billing" or "Subscription Management" only. That's why I reported it here. What's your advice?

Comment: No, you need a paid azure subscription. The other way would be through the office 365 administration portal if you have a paid office 365 subscription.