# Graph explorer fails with batch

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-batch

Using Graph Explorer I get the photo of a group with request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/12345678/photo/$value. Response preview shows the photo correctly.

When trying to get the photo of the same group using batch 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id":"12345678",
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"/groups/12345678/photo/$value"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get an error message "We had an issue sending this request to the Graph API. For assistance, connect with us on StackOverflow..."

This does not occur with all the groups. Is there something wrong with batch?

Comment: Are you seeing this for all group images, or just a specific group? Are you able to fetch the image metadata (`/groups/1234567/photo`)?

Comment: This occurs only with some of the groups. I am able to fetch the image metadata with `/groups/1234567/photo`. It seems that the error occurs with group photos where `"@odata.mediaContentType": "image/pjpeg"`. When the content type is image/jpeg also /$value works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the batch api regarding pjpeg images. Will be fixed soon. [similar issue with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808790/malformed-json-in-batch-when-getting-unified-group-images)